# Operating on index objects in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to convert my index in a Pandas dataframe to datetime objects so that I can select ranges of times.

Assuming that `my_df` is the dataframe that I am working with, I have the following:

```
# Conversion function:
def convert_times(x): return datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S.%f')

# Convert every index value in my dataframe
my_df.index = map(convert_times, my_df.index)
```

but I noticed that

```
map(convert_times, my_df.index)
```

returns a list, so the code above converts an index to a list, which is converted back to an index.

Is there a way to operate directly on an index object?

Comment: Do you really not have year/months/days? Surely these datetimes are going to just be junk (be in 1900)?

Comment: Thanks @Andy, I am afraid I don't, but yes, you are right, I get 1900 - 1- 1.

Comment: What were you hoping for (what do they mean)...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `to_datetime` directly:

```
datetime_format = '%H:%M:%S.%f' # tweak depending on format of dates

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format=format_datetime)
```

This will be *considerably* faster than using map (especially python's builtin map).

*Note: `to_datetime` doesn't require the format argument.*